# get the value as a collection for a JSONArray within a JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I have the below JSONObject. I have an attribute called results which is a JSONArray again which consist of JSONObjects. Now i am looking to see if there is any direct way to get id's in the form of a collection without explicitly creating and stroing in a map or a list. The expected output is :

**output:**

```
["123","345","567","891"]
```

**JSONObject:**

```
{
"status": {
    "status": "OK",
    "message": ""
},
"offset": 1,
"limit": "200",
"results": [
    {
      "id": “123”,
      "title": “title1”
    },
    {
       "id": “345”,
      "title": “title2”
    },
    {
       "id": “567”,
      "title": “title3”
    }, 

    {
      "id": “891”,
      "title": “title4”
    }
 ]
}
```

Right now i am getting the JSONArray results and iterating through it and saving the value of each iteration in a MAP.See below:

```
for (int k = 0; k <= resultsArray.length()-1 ; k++) {
    JSONObject j = resultsArray.getJSONObject(k);                                               
    id = j.getLong("id");
    map.put(title,
    "\"" + Long.toString(id) + "\"");
}
```

Reason for this:
 This is in a multithreaded environment and if i create a map that would be a shared resource and i need to synchronize it which locks the usage of this map by another thread which in turn resulting in a big performance issue in my case.

Any Suggestions please?

Comment: Do you mean "get all the id's at once without iterating through the JSONArray"?

Comment: @magicleon yes. So is there any predefined method i can use to get them in the form  of collection? i don't want to use a map here to save that for a specific reason(Reason: this is in a multithreaded environment and if i create a map that would be a shared resource and i need to synchronize it which locks the usage of this map by another thread which in turn resulting in a big performance issue in my case. ).

Comment: Well, I don't know of any method like this. You could make an `ArrayList<long>` and append all the id's, without using a map (you don't really need the map keys if you want that output). A `synchronized` method should be necessary either way, since I believe that even if a method like the one you want exists, it would involve more operations, bringing you back to a shared resource problem.

Comment: yes even if use a list it would be the same issue :( this is a big impact performance wise..:( Not sure if there is a solution @magicleon

Comment: When you say this is a "shared resource": are you creating the map once based on this JSON object and then reading it from a bunch of different threads, or are you actively updating the map based on inputs from multiple threads?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior basically 10 threads are processing a loop in which this map will be in picture to save the data.

Comment: When you say the map is "in picture", you mean that those threads will be making changes to this map as they process the loop? Or do you mean they'll all be needing information out of this map?

Comment: Each thread updates the map with new data @StriplingWarrior

Comment: Any suggestions please @StriplingWarrior

Comment: Maybe you can use [JsonPath](http://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-jayway-jsonpath) for extract this, but I never used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments it appears your concern is not so much with the creation of a list or hashmap, but rather that you're trying to coordinate the creation of the resulting collection across several different threads.

There are a lot of approaches you could take, and which is best will depend on your specific use case.

The simplest (code-wise) would probably be to use a collection that is implicitly concurrent, like [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) or a list wrapped in [Collections.synchronizedList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)). You may find that these collections perform better than trying to manage your own thread locking, but it's hard to say whether the performance will be sufficient for your case.

Another possibility would be to have each thread parse the json and produce a separate collection independently, so most of your work is done in a thread-safe manner, and then merge the results together in a single thread-safe/synchronized action at the end. This would only work if the list of ids is the desired output of your loops, and you don't need the intermediate results to be available before all of the threads have finished their processing. But if that works for you, then you'll probably get better performance that way than having 10 threads contending for a single resource all through the process.